# android BillingResult getResponseCode() какие коды бывают

Tags: android, android-billing

В классе billingResult есть метод getResponseCode(), но нигде не написали какие 
бывают коды. **Где можно посмотреть какие бывают коды?**

```
public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == 1) {   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например в документации: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.html.

Или просто в IDE, заглянув в исходики, в класс `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode`